# How to get rid of ConditionalExpression followed by plotting?

Tags: plotting, functions, evaluation

I have a function defined like this:

```
k=0.0000861733;
Func = 3*(T/D)^3 *
       Integrate[x^3/(Exp[x] - 1), {x, 0, D/T}, Assumptions -> T > 0, 
        Assumptions -> D > 0];
    F = (k*T)*(((9*D)/(8*T)) + (3*Log[1 - Exp[-D/T]]) - (Func/T));
```

I now simply want to have a derivative of `F` w.r.t `D`. So I use `D[F, {D, 1}]`

Which gives me following output:

```
    ConditionalExpression[
 0.0000861733 T (9/(8 T) + (3 E^(-(D/T)))/((1 - E^(-(D/T))) T) - (
    3 (-(D^3/T^4) - (D^3 E^(D/T))/((1 - E^(D/T)) T^4)) T^2)/D^3 + (
    9 T^2 (-(\[Pi]^4/15) - D^4/(4 T^4) + (D^3 Log[1 - E^(D/T)])/
       T^3 + (3 D^2 PolyLog[2, E^(D/T)])/T^2 - (
       6 D PolyLog[3, E^(D/T)])/T + 6 PolyLog[4, E^(D/T)]))/D^4), 
 E^(D/T) <= 1]
```

I have two questions hereafter. 1) First of all how to get rid of the `ConditionalExpression`? and then 2) How can I plot the derivative of that `F` as a function of `T` (say 1 < T < 1000) for a certain value of `D` let's say `D=200`? I would really appreciate if someone help me out a bit.

Comment: Try not to use symbol names starting with capital letters. These may collide with builtins.  `D` is a builtin and should not be used as a variable.

Comment: This code runs free of CE. `Func = 3*(T/d)^3*
  Integrate[x^3/(Exp[x] - 1), {x, 0, d/T}, 
   Assumptions -> {d > 0, T > 0}]`

Comment: It doesn't make much sense for `T>0,d>0` AND `E^(d/T) <= 1` For that, either `d` or `T` would have to be negative.

Comment: @Feyre: In My case both `d` and `T` is +ve.

Comment: @Feyre: It still gives me CE even after replacing `D` by `d` :( and what about the plot?

Comment: Did you merge the `Assumptions` as I suggested?

Comment: `Plot[F /. d -> 200, {T, 0, 100}]` Works fine.

Comment: @Feyre: Thank you. Could you please check once more whether you got the same graph or not? The plot I got can be found [here]( https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbuhqn3cbqtg3y1/pic.png?dl=0)

Comment: @Feyre: Just a moment, I assume this `plot` plots the function `F` itself? But I think I need to plot the derivative i.e., `F'`

Comment: @Feyre: Okay, I got it, thank you for your endeavor.

Comment: I do get the same plot.